# azure powerhsell integration account partner creation identities invalid

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-powershell

I have a paid and free integration account setup on Azure. I have already generated a few partners and agreements using the portal with no issues. Im now looking to use some powershell scripts to help control the creation of these partners and agreements in the future.

When trying to build script to create a partner I hit this bottleneck with the business identities.

> New-AzIntegrationAccountPartner -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName …
> |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> | Invalid business identity.

```
$ResourceGroupName = 'rg-test'
$IntegrationAccountName = 'inter-test'
$PartnerName = 'TestPartner'

$BusinessIdentities = @{
    Qualifier = "AS2Identity"
    Value = "TestIdentity"
}

New-AzIntegrationAccountPartner -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $IntegrationAccountName -PartnerName $PartnerName -BusinessIdentities $BusinessIdentities
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.logicapp/new-azintegrationaccountpartner?view=azps-4.6.1

Is there something Im unaware when it comes to hash-tables?

Powershell Core MacOS 10.15.6

Major  Minor  Patch  PreReleaseLabel BuildLabel

---

7      0      3

---

Update:

Adding Resolve-AzError Response.

```
HistoryId: 4

Message        : Invalid business identity.
StackTrace     :    at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.LogicApp.Utilities.CmdletHelper.ConvertToBusinessIdentityList(Object businessIdentityObject)
                    at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.LogicApp.Cmdlets.NewAzureIntegrationAccountPartnerCommand.ExecuteCmdlet()
                    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.CmdletExtensions.<>c__3`1.<ExecuteSynchronouslyOrAsJob>b__3_0(T c)
                    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.CmdletExtensions.ExecuteSynchronouslyOrAsJob[T](T cmdlet, Action`1 executor)
                    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.CmdletExtensions.ExecuteSynchronouslyOrAsJob[T](T cmdlet)
                    at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.AzurePSCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
Exception      : System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentException
InvocationInfo : {New-AzIntegrationAccountPartner}
Line           : New-AzIntegrationAccountPartner -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $IntegrationAccountName -PartnerName $PartnerName -BusinessIdentities 
                 $BusinessIdentities
Position       : At /Users/john/Desktop/run.ps1:10 char:1
                 + New-AzIntegrationAccountPartner -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName …
                 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
HistoryId      : 4
```

Comment: Please run the command `Resolve-AzError` to get the detailed error message and provide it.

Comment: Didn't know that was a command. @JimXu I have edited the post with the error. Not sure it helps us much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my research, when we run the command `New-AzIntegrationAccountPartner`, we need to define `BusinessIdentities` as Array. Becase the code `Microsoft.Azure.Commands.LogicApp.Utilities.CmdletHelper.ConvertToBusinessIdentityList(Object businessIdentityObject)` in the command `New-AzIntegrationAccountPartner` need users to provide Array object. Otherwise, it will throw error. For more details, please refer to [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/master/src/LogicApp/LogicApp.Test/ScenarioTests/IntegrationAccountPartnerTests.ps1#L19) and [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/master/src/LogicApp/LogicApp/Utilities/CmdletHelper.cs#L169).

For example

```
$ResourceGroupName = 'testaks'
$IntegrationAccountName = 'test06'
$PartnerName = 'TestPartner'

$BusinessIdentities = @("<the Qualifier's value such as AS2Identity>","<The Value's value>")

New-AzIntegrationAccountPartner -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $IntegrationAccountName -PartnerName $PartnerName -BusinessIdentities $BusinessIdentities
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @JimXu that worked. Not sure what the connection with a hash-table is here as they mentioned it in there own docs.